# How to write systemd environment variables value which contains =

Tags: linux, systemd

In systemd units file, I have a Environment which content is `key=IamValue=abc`, as you can see the value is `IamValue=abc` which contains `=`.

For this situation, how can I write the unit files?

I have tried as following, but it seems invalid:

```
[Unit]
Description=...

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=...
ExecStart=...
Restart=always
RestartSec=10                                          
SyslogIdentifier=...
User=root
Environment=key="IamValue=abc"
```

Comment: You can use enviroment file: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd#EnvironmentFiles_and_support_for_.2Fetc.2Fsysconfig_files.

Comment: "but it seems invalid", have you tried dumping the environment to see what it actually was? Should the quotes really be there?

Comment: @Kay You are right, it is working after I removed quotes. So the environment parser is just split by the first `=`? Didn't find document saying this.

Comment: It seemed the most logical implementation to me to split once at the first equals sign. When would you need an `=` in a key?

Comment: @Kay In my case, I'd like to store some key for my 3rd party service which is basically random string, so it may contains equal sign.

Comment: Sorry, I meant when would systemd need a line `aaa=bbb=ccc`, where it's parsed as `aaa=bbb` <=> `ccc`. `=` in a process environment are very common, of course (e.g. LS_COLORS and DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in my current bash).

Answer (score 6):

I tested that this works in a `test.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Hi

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=key="IamValue=abc"
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/bin/echo key:$key"
```

If you run that and then do `journalctl -u test`, you can see the key containing the equal sign works.

I've proposed an [update to the official systemd docs](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/5710) to better clarify this case.

Comment: Funny, I just wasted 2 hours yesterday because I wrote Environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="something.settings" and systemd created a variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE whose value was "something.settings", double quotes included... >___>

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use `EnvironmentFile`, config line in unit file:

```
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/test
```

With content in `/etc/sysconfig/test`:

```
key="IamValue=abc"
```